# How do I repair stripped threads of a tripod mount?

Tags: repair, tripod-socket

The tripod mount of my Canon 1Ds has been worn out and I need to repair it. I've been searching the Internet and found [this method involving using a Helicoil Eco kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whoeBQSEMbM). It seems like a sensible (both regarding cost and quality) solution. Are there any downsides of this method? Is there another perhaps better solution? Sending it to Canon I'm sure would cost a lot and maybe even more than getting another 1Ds and is not an option.

Comment: The one thing that I would do differently from the video is to take steps to protect your camera from the metal filings (you really don't want those migrating into anything mechanical or electrical).

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Yes, I agree. The 1Ds bodies seem to have a battery compartment that is pretty isolated to the rest of the camera, but that is no reason not to be careful.

Answer (score 5):

The mounting hole on the bottom of the camera should be a "blind nut" style hole - meaning you should be able to replace the whole metal part, but you're gonna have to get way inside the camera to do it, so it's probably not something you want to do yourself. I don't know the design of that one enough to answer - it might be easy, it might be hard. It might be impossible to get the part. Helicoil re-threading works great but in situations where I've done it, it's been on car engines and we had to make the diameter bigger. Keep in mind it won't work on a tripod unless it remains the exact same size.

Answer (score 3):

Helicoils can be successfully used in many mechanical situations, but I'd be very worried that it will not work well on your 1Ds.

Installing a Helicoil is fairly simple: you tap out the existing threads with a special oversized tap, and then insert the new coil of threads into the now larger hole. Most of the effort is in cutting the metal to make the new larger threads, but you may also cut into the bottom of the threads, deepening the hole.

The problem is that you don't know how much extra material is available. If you break into the camera body, you will probably cause a light leak. You may also cause a dust/dirt leak.

Comment: If you need to retap anyway, and if there is enough metal for that, simply re-tapping the mount straight into 3/8" might be an option too...